# Flexbox overflow issue in Firefox

Tags: html, css, angularjs, firefox, flexbox

I'm getting stuck on a test project using flexbox. The goal is to build a dashboard with some lists of cards inside, side-by-side with infinite overflowing.

I managed to do just that, the problem is: each one those lists have a header, a card list and a footer inside, and the lists height can't exceed the parent available height. If that happen, the list must only apply overflow on the card list.

On chrome it works just fine, but on firefox... It seems the renderer can't handle the possibility of the content overflowing that way! I'm getting really mad with this one.

Example:

**The code (also on [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/0jYmZs2Fn8P4Lur8k5LQ/))**

```js
// Code goes here
(function (angular) {
  angular.module("app", []);  
  
  angular.module("app").controller("AppController", AppController);
  
  AppController.$inject = ["$scope"];
  
  function AppController($scope) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.addCard = function (list) {
      list.cards.push({title: "Card " + (list.cards.length + 1)});
    };
    ctrl.lists = [
      {
        title: "List 1",
        cards: [
          {title: "Card 1"},
          {title: "Card 2"},
          {title: "Card 3"},
          {title: "Card 4"},
          {title: "Card 5"}
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "List 2",
        cards: [
          {title: "Card 1"},
          {title: "Card 2"},
          {title: "Card 3"},
          {title: "Card 4"},
          {title: "Card 5"},
          {title: "Card 6"},
          {title: "Card 7"},
          {title: "Card 8"},
          {title: "Card 9"},
          {title: "Card 10"},
          {title: "Card 11"},
          {title: "Card 12"},
          {title: "Card 13"},
          {title: "Card 14"},
          {title: "Card 15"},
          {title: "Card 16"},
          {title: "Card 17"},
          {title: "Card 18"},
          {title: "Card 19"},
          {title: "Card 20"}
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "List 3",
        cards: [
          {title: "Card 1"},
          {title: "Card 2"},
          {title: "Card 3"},
          {title: "Card 4"},
          {title: "Card 5"}
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "List 4",
        cards: [
          {title: "Card 1"},
          {title: "Card 2"},
          {title: "Card 3"},
          {title: "Card 4"},
          {title: "Card 5"}
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "List 5",
        cards: [
          {title: "Card 1"},
          {title: "Card 2"},
          {title: "Card 3"},
          {title: "Card 4"},
          {title: "Card 5"}
        ]
      }
    ];
  }
}(angular))
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  float: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .container-head {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
  -moz-flex-grow: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.container .container-head .header-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container .container-body {
  background: green;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container .container-body .view {
  background: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container .container-body .view .list-block {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: darkblue;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 280px;
  min-height:0;
}

.container .container-body .view .list-block .list {
  background: darkorange;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .container-body .view .list-block .list .list-header {
  background: orange;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkorange;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 0 0 auto;
  -moz-flex-grow: 0 0 auto;
  flex-grow: 0 0 auto;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container .container-body .view .list-block .list .list-cards {
  background: orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkorange;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container .container-body .view .list-block .list .list-cards .card {
  background: #ffc107;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container .container-body .view .list-block .list .list-cards .card:hover {
  background: #fdc002;
}

.container .container-body .view .list-block .list .list-footer {
  background: orange;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
  -moz-flex-grow: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div class="flexbox container" ng-controller="AppController as ctrl">
      <div class="container-head">
        <h3 class="header-title">Flexbox</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="container-body">
        <div class="view">
          <div class="list-block" ng-repeat="list in ctrl.lists">
            <div class="list">
              <div class="list-header">{{list.title}}</div>
              <div class="list-cards">
                <div class="card" ng-repeat="card in list.cards">
                  {{card.title}}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="list-footer">
                <a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="ctrl.addCard(list)">
                  Add Card
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**On Chrome** (Everything working)
[image: On Chrome works!]

**On Firefox** (Doesn't apply the vertical overflow control correctly)
[image]

Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: did you tried fixing the max-height of the container?

Comment: An initial setting on flex items is `min-height: auto`. This means that flex items cannot be shorter than the height of their content. Chrome automatically adjust for this, which is why your layout works there. Firefox, Edge and others adhere strictly to the spec. You need to override this default for cross-browser compatibility. Use `min-height: 0` on the overflowing item.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks much for that tip. I've been wondering why Firefox's handling of flex is different than Chrome's in so many cases (requiring work-arounds), but it seems the difference you listed above is the cause of most of them! Saves a lot of time being able to use a standard fix instead of maxHeight: "calc(100% - margin)" workarounds.

Comment: @Venryx, you're welcome. Glad I could help. For a more detailed explanation see the bottom of my answer ("Browser Rendering Notes") here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276

Comment: Hmm, the latest version of Chrome appears to be requiring the `min-height: 0;` fix as well. Has anyone else noticed this, or am I mistaking something? (your demo above does not have in-list scrolling in Chrome anymore, which doesn't match your screenshot anymore)

Comment: Okay, the change appears to have been made in Chrome by this developer here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=927066#c39

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just put `min-height: 0;` to .container-body this will fix your issue

```
.container .container-body {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

See this answer for [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28639686/2724173)

Comment: Dude, you're a life saver. I tried to do that, but not in the .container-body. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Like I want to upvote 100 times...

Comment: This is the fix for Firefox only. For the same issues in IE11 use min-height: 1px;

Comment: Hmm, the latest version of Chrome appears to be requiring the `min-height: 0;` fix as well. Has anyone else noticed this, or am I mistaking something? (see OP demo in Chrome -- doesn't have in-list scrolling anymore for me)

Comment: Okay, the change appears to have been made in Chrome by this developer here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=927066#c39

Comment: yes it's not working in chrome either