# Flexbox div won't scroll on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I have a `div` dropdown element. I'm using flexbox so I can easily order the contents using `order`:

```css
.dropdown-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <div class="selectable" style="order: 700">Something</div>
  <div class="selectable" style="order: 100">Something</div>
  <div class="selectable" style="order: 800">Something</div>
</div>
```

This works fine on Chrome, the content is scrollable, but Firefox refuses to show scrollbars. If I force the scrollbars, by setting  `overflow-y: scroll;` they're just disabled scrollbars.

I've tried adding `min-height:0; min-width:0;` but that does nothing.

Comment: Is this question helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636832/firefox-overflow-y-not-working-with-nested-flexbox

Comment: I can't see any of that. Please make the code to reflect your problem.

Comment: I had the same kind of problem with FF on a chat application where i needed column-reverse... Their implementation of flexboxes feels still buggy when it comes to column-reverse...

Comment: This answer of mine has some more info and sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213227/scrollable-div-to-stick-to-bottom-when-outer-div-changes-in-size/34330934#34330934