# Bootstrap 4, full-height, full-width layout, chrome ok, firefox/ie11 not

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, overflow, bootstrap-4

I have a simple prototype of what I'm trying to do. Chrome is fine with it, but it doesn't work in firefox or IE11 (haven't tried Edge). I'm using 'container-fluid' to get full width, '[h-100](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/)' to get full-height, and 'overflow-y' because I want to be able my left and right sections to scroll vertically as needed. What I see is the left-hand section contents overflows the section. I tried adding 'min-height' [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28639686/231039), but it didn't make a difference.

Is this a bootstrap bug (this is beta 2), or is there some additional styles I need to set?

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <style>
    .border {
      border-width: 5px !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid h-100 border border-danger">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 h-100 border border-success"
         style="overflow-y: auto;">
      <div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse placerat, turpis ac porttitor sodales, turpis magna facilisis quam, eget efficitur neque tortor sit amet risus. </p>
            <span class="active">More...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse placerat, turpis ac porttitor sodales, turpis magna facilisis quam, eget efficitur neque tortor sit amet risus. </p>
            <span class="active">More...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse placerat, turpis ac porttitor sodales, turpis magna facilisis quam, eget efficitur neque tortor sit amet risus. </p>
            <span class="active">More...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse placerat, turpis ac porttitor sodales, turpis magna facilisis quam, eget efficitur neque tortor sit amet risus. </p>
            <span class="active">More...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse placerat, turpis ac porttitor sodales, turpis magna facilisis quam, eget efficitur neque tortor sit amet risus. </p>
            <span class="active">More...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col h-100 border border-primary"
         style="overflow-y: auto;">
      Info...<br>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Wide_panorama_of_Aam_Talab_Lake%2C_Raichur.jpg/1280px-Wide_panorama_of_Aam_Talab_Lake%2C_Raichur.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the problem lies with `height: 100%` somewhere along the DOM structure. This may get you closer: https://jsfiddle.net/mbeuu6tp/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you hit one of the most common error when using percent based height.

An element using percent for its height won't work unless the element's parent have a height (or being position absolute), and if the parent also use percent, its parent need a height, and so on, until the `html` element is reached, which get its height from the viewport's height.

By adding `h100` to the `.row` and this rule, it will work

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.border {
  border-width: 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid h-100 border border-danger">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-3 h-100 border border-success"
         style="overflow-y: auto;">
      <div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse placerat, turpis ac porttitor sodales, turpis magna facilisis quam, eget efficitur neque tortor sit amet risus. </p>
            <span class="active">More...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse placerat, turpis ac porttitor sodales, turpis magna facilisis quam, eget efficitur neque tortor sit amet risus. </p>
            <span class="active">More...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse placerat, turpis ac porttitor sodales, turpis magna facilisis quam, eget efficitur neque tortor sit amet risus. </p>
            <span class="active">More...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse placerat, turpis ac porttitor sodales, turpis magna facilisis quam, eget efficitur neque tortor sit amet risus. </p>
            <span class="active">More...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse placerat, turpis ac porttitor sodales, turpis magna facilisis quam, eget efficitur neque tortor sit amet risus. </p>
            <span class="active">More...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col h-100 border border-primary"
         style="overflow-y: auto;">
      Info...<br>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Wide_panorama_of_Aam_Talab_Lake%2C_Raichur.jpg/1280px-Wide_panorama_of_Aam_Talab_Lake%2C_Raichur.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So close and yet so far! At least for this sample, the style on html & body doesn't seem necessary. From the dev console, I now see that "h-100" is adding "height: 100%!important", and I now have that on the container, the row, and the cols. I guess that chrome treats that as being inherited by the row, where I had it missing. Thanks!

Comment: I take back what I said about the height on html,body....I needed to add that to my angular app to get the desired behavior.