# Bootstrap 4 tab overflow content not scrolling

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, overflow, bootstrap-tabs

Working on a Bootstrap 4 Holy Grail layout.

Each column should scroll overflowing content independently and without declaring a height. The far left column scrolls properly. The far right column though has a Bootstrap NAV/TAB widget. The third tab of which, **MENU 2**, contains overflowing content that won't scroll no matter what I try.

**What am I missing?** Any assistance would be appreciated!

Here is the pertinent CSS:

```
.flex_item2 {
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/Db0rEUYvXn

Thank you so much!

[image: Bootstrap 4 Holy Grail]

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Apparently FF (35.0.1 +) and IE11 do not scroll well with nested flex boxes. Here are the workarounds.

[firefox overflow-y not working with nested flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636832/firefox-overflow-y-not-working-with-nested-flexbox)

https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/164

I will update the Bootstrap 4 Holy Grail layout code to reflect the workaround. Enjoy!