# Full height bootstrap grid - with nested overflow-y: scroll

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

I have problems with the bootstrap grid and a nested div with overflow-y.
Like mentioned in [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28639686), I tried to add a `min-height:0`
to the parent ancestor, but can't get it to run.

[left Chrome, right: Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMq8e.png)

In Chrome the layout is rendered okay (no browser scrollbar) and a scrollbar in the red area marked with the overflow-y: scroll.

In Firefox the layout isn't rendered okay (browser scrollbar is shown, no scrollbar in red area)

My goal is to have a 100% height webpage with a vertical splitted right column (25% | 75%) and a scrollbar in the red area in all browsers ;-)

I've put the sources to a [codepen](https://codepen.io/cluen/full/RqVEWN)

Any suggestions, how to achieve the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've adjusted your code a little, please check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1x0jyvm/).

Try adding `height: 100vh;` to `.bg-secondary`. Additionally I've moved the `overflow-y: scroll` to `.bg-danger`

And make sure you have imported all necessary bootstrap files, I've used bootstrap.min.js(v4.1.3), bootstrap.css (v4.1.3), popper.min.js (1.12.9), jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js