# Flexbox overflow-y scroll in Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For a chat application, I want to have a scroll-able message list. It works in Chrome / Chromium, but not in Firefox. The problem seems related to [flexbug #1](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-1) and has been asked & addressed often enough here on SO. However, despite trying `min-height:0` on all parents as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28639686/3104318) and elsewhere, the problem remains.

One quick fix is to remove `display:flex` from `.bot-message-list`. But doing so results in messages starting to appear on top of the list, instead of at the bottom as is intended.

So the question is: what can I change in order to make the message list scroll-able on all browsers while having the initial messages starting to populate at the bottom of the list.

[Codepen of the current state](https://codepen.io/citivin/pen/OJMpGLP)

Any pointers are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try add height on element ".message-list-inner".

```css
.message-list-inner {
     height: 100vh; /* or height: 100%;*/
}
```

For a brief look it seems to work.